# Joomla Google Fonts and GDPR

Tags: joomla, google-fonts

I received an email from client said that the site is violating GDPR  related to the use of Google Fonts. they said this was the issue
Roboto
https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxK.woff2

but i tried to search the whole site, I cant find anything regarding those font above, no fonts.gstatic, no robot nor .woff2 file.

is it possible joomla load file on the fly that not from our site? or anyone have this kind of issue too?

Comment: Please post Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Search the mail address, or the mail author. I was receiving similar mail and I discovered that was a SCAM.
If you are using ready-made Joomla template, is impossible that you don't have the copyright to use the font that is included in the template.